# reading from File in assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, dos

i am trying to read a username and a password from a file in x86 assembly for the perpose of authentication
obviously the file consists of two lines , the user name and the password how can i read the two lines seperately and compare them?

My attempt:

```
proc read_file

  mov ah,3dh
  lea dx,file_name
  int 21h

  mov bx, ax 
  xor si,si

repeat:

  mov ah, 3fh
  lea dx, buffer
  mov cx, 100 
  int 21h

  mov si, ax
  mov buffer[si], '$'
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h ;print on screen


  cmp si, 100
  je repeat 

  jmp stop;jump to end
stop:
   RET
    read_file ENDP
```

Comment: x86 family , i will edit it now thanks

Comment: And what operating system? and why on earth are you writing this in assembler?

Comment: i'm using windows 7 32b, it is a part of a project asked by our assembly professor

Comment: Could have been helpful to know you wanted to a DOS program.
And what kind of problems you are having with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28VS.85%29.aspx) and read up on functions like CreateFile and ReadFile.

Comment: i beleive this is high level ,i'm talking assembly , but thanks thpugh

Comment: I believe you said windows 7, and that's as low as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You should use system class to do that and it depends on whether you use Windows or Linux.
Check this : http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html